# How to write interface test cases without interface testing documentation

Tags: testing, interface

When testing an interface, the request data and response data of the interface test case are directly viewed through packet capture to view the passed parameters and expected response data. Assuming that the data returned by the interface is incorrect, referring to the captured data as the expected result should not be incorrect

When testing an interface, the request data and response data of the interface test case are directly viewed through packet capture to view the passed parameters and expected response data. Assuming that the data returned by the interface is incorrect, referring to the captured data as the expected result should not be incorrect

I hope you can answer me, thank you very much！